# why can't I connect python to firebird in ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: python, firebird

Hi I'm novice in python and firebird too, my problem is i'm trying to connect my python program to a database in firebird, I've installed firebird (is currently on /opt/firebird) I have created my database(test.fdb) with a table(it works fine in the firebird)

```
create table languages
(
  name               varchar(20),
  year_released      integer
);

insert into languages (name, year_released) values ('C',        1972);
insert into languages (name, year_released) values ('Python',   1991);
```

but when i'm trying to run in pydev occurs a problem.

```
import fdb

con = fdb.connect(dsn="/tmp/test.fdb", user="fernando", password="root")

# Create a Cursor object that operates in the context of Connection con:
cur = con.cursor()

# Execute the SELECT statement:
cur.execute("select * from languages")

# Retrieve all rows as a sequence and print that sequence:
print cur.fetchall()
```

http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/drivers_documentation/python/fdb/getting-started.html

current location of databse is on /tmp, I'm using fdb downloaded from here: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/fdb/ and installed with pip also I used in pydev properties->pydev pythonpath and added the folder of fdb (it seems normal so far with no errors),my username is fernando and password is root, so when I finally run I get this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/elfstone/Documents/workspace/NuevosPython/fire.py", line 3, in <module>
    con = fdb.connect(dsn="/tmp/test.fdb", user="fernando", password="root")
  File "/home/elfstone/Downloads/fdb-1.4/fdb/fbcore.py", line 693, in connect
    "Error while connecting to database:")
fdb.fbcore.DatabaseError: ('Error while connecting to database:\n- SQLCODE: -902\n- Unable to complete network request to host "localhost".\n- Failed to establish a connection.', -902, 335544721)
```

How can this be fixed? help and thanks.

Comment: Is the Firebird server up and running, some tools of Firebird might use an embedded database engine for some connections, but fdb by default needs to connect to the actual server.

Answer (score 1):

Checked with `Ubuntu 12.04.4` and `fdb 1.4.1` all suggested statement types are working:

```
fdb.connect(dsn="/var/lib/firebird/2.5/data/test.fdb", user="fernando", password="root")
fdb.connect(host="localhost", database="/var/lib/firebird/2.5/data/test.fdb", user="fernando", password="root")
fdb.connect(dsn="localhost:/var/lib/firebird/2.5/data/test.fdb", user="fernando", password="root")
```

Answer (score 0):

This is untested, but my suspicion is:

The error says you cannot connect to 'localhost', which is a network name for the computer you are using. However, you ask Firebird to connect to '/tmp/test.fbd', which is a file system location. Basically, firebird thinks that the you want to connect to the file '/tmp/test.fbd' as if it were a server.

Try:

```
con = fdb.connect(host="localhost", database="/tmp/test.fdb", user="fernando", password="root")
```

or

```
con = fdb.connect(dsn="localhost:/tmp/test.fdb", user="fernando", password="root")
```

Assuming of course, that /tmp/fest.fbd is actually on your localhost.

Comment: Local protocol (if hostname is not specified) might work depending on the environment, see http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/drivers_documentation/python/fdb/usage-guide.html#databases

Comment: hi, tanks for the reply , it does not work, with the first option:con = fdb.connect(host="localhost", path="/tmp/test.fdb", user="fernando", password="root")
TypeError: connect() got an unexpected keyword argument 'path' and the second is the same thing, I tried all posibilities(dsn=localhost/3050:/tmp/test.fdb" for example), what is the path where it suppose to be my localhos?

Comment: I've changed the answer to use the correct 'database' argument instead of 'path' - apologies for that. Note that the address in you comment is not valid (you have a slash before the port number).